# Extending of pure function with IO code possible?

Tags: haskell, types, io, monads, referential-transparency

I've written a simple XML parser in Haskell.
The function *convertXML* recieves contents of a XML file and returns a list of extracted values that are further processed.

One attribute of XML tag contains also an URL of a product image and I would like to extend the function to also download it if the tag is found.

```
convertXML ::  (Text.XML.Light.Lexer.XmlSource s) => s -> [String]
convertXML xml = productToCSV products
    where
        productToCSV [] = []
        productToCSV (x:xs) = (getFields x) ++ (productToCSV
                                (elChildren x)) ++ (productToCSV xs)
        getFields elm = case (qName . elName) elm of
                            "product" -> [attrField "uid", attrField "code"]
                            "name" -> [trim $ strContent elm]
                            "annotation" -> [trim $ strContent elm]
                            "text" -> [trim $ strContent elm]
                            "category" -> [attrField "uid", attrField "name"]
                            "manufacturer" -> [attrField "uid",
                                                attrField "name"]
                            "file" -> [getImgName]
                            _ -> []
            where
                attrField fldName = trim . fromJust $
                                        findAttr (unqual fldName) elm
                getImgName = if (map toUpper $ attrField "type") == "FULL"
                                then
                                    -- here I need some IO code
                                    -- to download an image
                                    -- fetchFile :: String -> IO String
                                    attrField "file"
                                else []
        products = findElements (unqual "product") productsTree
        productsTree = fromJust $ findElement (unqual "products") xmlTree
        xmlTree = fromJust $ parseXMLDoc xml
```

Any idea how to insert an IO code in the ***getImgName*** function or do I have to completely rewrite convertXML function to an impure version ?

**UPDATE II**
Final version of convertXML function. Hybrid pure/impure but clean way suggested by Carl. Second parameter of returned pair is an IO action that runs images downloading and saving to disk and wraps list of local paths where are images stored.

```
convertXML ::  (Text.XML.Light.Lexer.XmlSource s) => s -> ([String], IO [String])
convertXML xml = productToCSV products (return [])
    where
        productToCSV :: [Element] -> IO String -> ([String], IO [String])
        productToCSV [] _ = ([], return [])
        productToCSV (x:xs) (ys) = storeFields (getFields x)
                            ( storeFields (productToCSV (elChildren x) (return []))
                                (productToCSV xs ys) )
        getFields elm = case (qName . elName) elm of
                            "product" -> ([attrField "uid", attrField "code"], return [])
                            "name" -> ([trim $ strContent elm], return [])
                            "annotation" -> ([trim $ strContent elm], return [])
                            "text" -> ([trim $ strContent elm], return [])
                            "category" -> ([attrField "uid", attrField "name"], return [])
                            "manufacturer" -> ([attrField "uid",
                                                attrField "name"], return [])
                            "file" -> getImg
                            _ -> ([], return [])
            where
                attrField fldName = trim . fromJust $
                                        findAttr (unqual fldName) elm
                getImg = if (map toUpper $ attrField "type") == "FULL"
                            then
                                ( [attrField "file"], fetchFile url >>=
                                    saveFile localPath >>
                                    return [localPath] )
                                else ([], return [])
                    where
                        fName = attrField "file"
                        localPath = imagesDir ++ "/" ++ fName
                        url = attrField "folderUrl" ++ "/" ++ fName

        storeFields (x1s, y1s) (x2s, y2s) = (x1s ++ x2s, liftM2 (++) y1s y2s)
        products = findElements (unqual "product") productsTree
        productsTree = fromJust $ findElement (unqual "products") xmlTree
        xmlTree = fromJust $ parseXMLDoc xml
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41522491/is-there-a-way-to-place-some-impure-code-inside-pure-functions .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The entire point of the type system in Haskell is that you can't do IO except with IO actions - values of type IO a.  There are ways to violate this, but they run the risk of behaving entirely unlike what you'd expect, due to interactions with optimizations and lazy evaluation.  So until you understand why IO works the way it does, don't try to make it work differently.

But a very important consequence of this design is that IO actions are first class.  With a bit of cleverness, you could write your function as this:

```
convertXML ::  (Text.XML.Light.Lexer.XmlSource s) => s -> ([String], IO [Image])
```

The second item in the pair would be an IO action that, when executed, would give a list of the images present.  That would avoid the need to have image loading code outside of convertXML, and it would allow you to do IO only if you actually needed the images.

Comment: That sounds like a nice idea to return "value" of IO action type as a second argument. Any hints how to update my -> ([String], [String]) version to -> ([String], IO [String]) ?

Comment: Well, I don't think `String` is the right type for an image.  Assuming you want the bytes returned by the URL, you'd want to use `ByteString` for the representation, not String.  String is for character data, and includes unicode codepoints.  ByteString is for efficiently handling sequences of bytes, as an image in binary form might be.  Given a function like `fetch :: String -> IO ByteString` that takes a URL, you can convert a list of URLs to an IO action to fetch them with `mapM fetch urls`.

Comment: Thanks Carl. I did intended accessing IO [String] will return list of URLs of images and downloading them to disk will be invoked as its "side effect".

Comment: I guess you could do that, but how useful is the URL in that case?  Wouldn't you rather have the path on disk as the return value, instead?  In any case, you can do what you want.

Answer (score 4):

The better approach would be to have the function return the list of files to download as part of the result:

```
convertXML ::  (Text.XML.Light.Lexer.XmlSource s) => s -> ([String], [URL])
```

and download them in a separate function.

Comment: Modularization is good, and is definitely what the "inability to stick an IO value here" is telling you.

Answer (score 2):

I basically see to approaches:

1. let the function give out a list of found images too and process them with an impure function afterwards. Laziness will do the rest.
2. Make the whole beast impure

I generally like the first approach more. d

Comment: Thanks for the advices. I'm going to rewrite the function to return list of urls as an extra list in a tuple. To do it in a "one pass" ie. without creating and processing additional list of urls I guess only impure version is the solution ?

Comment: The optimizations are often clever enough to remove the typical build a list eat it behavior. Don't worry about efficience.

Comment: Well... do worry about it, but initally only pay attention to computational complexity (O(n) rather than O(n^2)).  Worry about constant factors like producer-consumer overhead only after getting the clean-and-simple version to work and using the profiler to demonstrate that it is taking too much time.